# using curl with -d param1=value1 seems not work properly

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I have a shell Unix running every hour (crontab on CentOS 7).

Inside that shell, a loop read and proceed treatment for all new files find in a defined folder.
At the end of each files's treatment a CURL command is send with some parameters, for example :

```
curl https://aaaaaa.com/website -d param1=value1 -d param2=value2 ....
```

Each time the shell is run by crontab, the 1st CURL is correctly converted to a true URL and received by Apache/Tomcat, but all the others are bad. In fact the 2nd and the following CURLs seem not converted in the correct format like

```
https://aaaaaa.com/website?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

but they are sent like

```
https://aaaaaa.com/website -d param1=value1 -d param2=value2
```

So the website is unable to treat the parameters properly.

Why the 1st command is correctly converted to a correct URL format and not the following ?

EDIT - EDIT

The part of shell :

```
#!/bin/bash

...

#======================================================
#   FUNCTIONS
#======================================================

UpdateStatus () {

    CMD_CURL="${URL_WEBSITE} -d client=CLIENT -d site=TEST -d produit=MEDIASFILES -d action=update"
    CMD_CURL="${CMD_CURL} -d codecmd=UPDATE_MEDIA_STATUS"
    CMD_CURL="${CMD_CURL} -d idmedia=$4"
    CMD_CURL="${CMD_CURL} -d idbatch=$3"
    CMD_CURL="${CMD_CURL} -d statusmedia=$2"
    if [[ ! -z "$5" ]]; then
        CMD_CURL="${CMD_CURL} -d filename=$5"
    fi
    echo "      ${CMD_CURL}" >> $1
    CURL_RESULT=`curl -k ${CMD_CURL}`
    CURL_RESULT=`echo ${CURL_RESULT} | tr -d ' '`
    echo "      Result CURL = ${CURL_RESULT}" >> $1
    if [ "${CURL_RESULT}" = "OK" ]; then
        return 0
    fi  
    return 1

}


#======================================================
#   MAIN PROGRAM
#======================================================

echo "----- Batch in progress : `date '+%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S'` -----"

for file in $( ls ${DIR_FACTORY_BATCHFILES}/*.batch )
do

    ...

    old_IFS=$IFS
    while IFS=';' read <&3 F_STATUS F_FILEIN F_TYPE F_CODE F_ID F_IDPARENT F_TAGID3 F_PROF F_YEARMEDIA F_DATECOURS F_TIMEBEGINCOURS F_LANG  || [[ -n "$F_STATUS $F_FILEIN $F_TYPE $F_CODE $F_ID $F_IDPARENT $F_TAGID3 $F_PROF $F_YEARMEDIA $F_DATECOURS $F_TIMEBEGINCOURS $F_LANG" && $F_STATUS ]];
    do

        ...

        UpdateStatus ${LOG_FILENAME} ${STATUS_ERROR} ${F_ID} ${F_IDPARENT}

        ...

    done 3< $file
    IFS=$Old_IFS

    ...

done
```

Comment: Can you share a part of your script about the curl loop?

Comment: Sounds like you are doing the equivalent of `curl 'https://aaaaaa.com/website -d param1=value1 -d param2=value2'`, so that each `-d` and its argument is considered part of the URL argument, rather than separate arguments to `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the "-d" flags and values before the URL so:

```
curl -d param1=value1 -d param2=value2 https://aaaaaa.com/website
```

Moreover, this command is going to send the parameters/values as POST parameters, not query parameters. You can use the "-G" flag, possibly combined with "--url-encode" to send as query parameters, see:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command